# Is there a way to natively return the full filesystem path when using $wp_styles?

Tags: globals, filesystem

Looping through `global $wp_styles`, `$wp_styles->registered[$style]->src` returns the URL of the resource e.g. `https://domain.com/path/to/file/`.

I'd like to source the local filesystem path instead e.g. `/home/public_html/path/to/file/` instead.

Currently, I have to replace the values like so `str_replace( home_url(), untrailingslashit( ABSPATH ), $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src )`

Is this the only way?

Comment: I've left an answer, however I see you did not say why you need this, if you had I could have suggested an alternative solution to your problem ( this is a classic X Y problem )

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks. You're right. The outcome I'm looking for is to combine the various stylesheets.

Comment: note that this will reduce performance on HTTP2 connections, WP core itself combines stylesheets on the admin as it was a good optimisation in the 2000's and early 2010's but has seen recent calls to undo this as it's now hurting rather than helping performance. The original advice was meant to avoid creating multiple connections to grab files, but HTTP/2 can do that over a single connection, and the vast majority of servers support HTTP2 or even HTTP3 connections. There's also the problem that reading in and merging stylesheets isn't instant and takes server time

Comment: @TomJNowell, I'm assuming that you won't see a difference for connections over HTTP/2 and 3 if the stylesheets are inline.

Comment: doing that carries its own problems as now the stylesheets can't be cached and reused on subsequent page loads, they're always sent in full with every page. Also don't forget that you'll be breaking relative paths referencing images fonts etc so additional work is needed to fix that. If the goal is improving frontend performance then this is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to natively return the full filesystem path when using $wp_styles?

No because the style engine is never given the filesystem path, it is only given the source URL of the style to be registered/enqueued via `wp_enqueue_style`:

> wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Only the code that called it would know that information, and it's usually handled in such a way that you'd need to speak with the developer to know with 100% certainty.

For this reason there is no WordPress API or filter you can use to get the path of an enqueued file. The best you can do is apply a heuristic.

#### The Closest You Can Get

You can check if the URL is for your own site and contains `wp-content`, then swap the domain out for a file path and see if a file exists at that location, and if a file is found do what you needed to do.

This won't always work though as the URL could be for a dynamic page rather than a static file, which is the case for concatenated admin scripts, or assets that have been minified by plugins. I expect any system would be broken by plugins like W3 Total Cache or Autoptimise, and CDN plugins may break this by rewriting the URLs to 3rd party servers.

Comment: thanks. Can you expand on what you mean by a 'dynamic page' as well as what you mean by `I expect any system would be broken by plugins like W3 Total Cache or Autoptimise, and CDN plugins may break this by rewriting the URLs to 3rd party servers`

Comment: because if the enqueued script has a URL like this https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js obviously you can't figure out the filesystem path, likewise some plugins will take the enqueued files and change them so that instead of referencing the file they reference a PHP script so that it can do processing such as minification or merging multiple scripts. A good example of this is the WP Admin stylesheets which are loaded via a dedicated PHP file by default rather than using a direct URL to the CSS file. Plugins can also load stylesheets generated by PHP that have no file